# Python gives a floating number where it should simply gives integer

Tags: python, python-3.x

Does anyone have an idea why this is happening?

```
>>> 289.6*(100-50)
14480.000000000002
```

it should give just **14480** !!

I tried something else and it confused me more

```
>>> 289.6*10*5
14480.0
```

so why the first one gives **14480.000000000002** and the second gives **14480.0** while it is the same!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

python converts up to float because of your 289.6. if you want an int, try
`int(289.6*(100-50))`
and that will cast the answer to int.
The reason your result has the crazy .0000000002 at the end is because of how floats are stored in computers. For a more in depth read on that, [read this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/floating-point-error-in-python/)

Comment: Fair enough, let me edit right quick and explain

Answer (score 3):

This is because of floating point precision.  In fact, `0.3 - 0.2 != 0.1`, because computers use binary instead of decimal.  [Here's a link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/why-0-3-0-2-is-not-equal-to-0-1-in-python/) explaining why.

If you really need precision, you can use the `decimal` library:

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> Decimal("289.6")*(100-50)
Decimal('14480.0')
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look here:
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html

The gist of it is that floating-point numbers are approximations. In your case, this is probably an approximation of a binary number, displayed as a decimal one.

Comment: You have it backwards.  The number is binary, but it's approximating a decimal one.  It's possible to display a binary number precisely in decimal, but it takes a lot more digits than you expect.